# Practical eCommerce / CMS solution for webpage with restricted content to paying users

Tags: php, drupal, magento, content-management-system, e-commerce

The web application has following prerequisites:

- Written in PHP
- Several menues, also a hierarchy so that there are second and third level navigational elements dependent on the active trail
- Usergroups with different access restrictions
- Pages that are differently displayed dependent on the usergroup of the current visitor
- Registered users should be able to comment a specific subgroup of pages
- Possibility to use different **payment methods** to buy extended access for a specific period of time, with generation invoice documents
- Creation of coupon codes to reduce the prices

Well, most stuff is pretty basic CMS stuff, but the last two points is eCommerce related. Currently the app is realized as Drupal 7 / Ubercart webpage, but these are packages in BETA state, so i'd like to see if there are other solutions.

Magento? Is Magento capable of that CMS stuff?

Or Magento with a bridge to another CMS like Drupal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal 7 was released over a year ago now and Ubercart is in RC3. Where did you get that info?
They are both pretty stable. Drupal 6 would be an alternative too.

Those requirements seem easy enough with Drupal and Ubercart so I wouldn't get them out of the table since Drupal has a large userbase and great support on the forums and IRC.

Comment: The problem is: There is a Coupon module for Ubercart (http://drupal.org/project/uc_coupon), but it doesn't work that well. There is wrong output of the prices, problems when paying via Paypal and no good possibility to make tax-inclusive discounts.

Comment: I'll accept this answer since i still use Drupal 7 in combination with Ubercart.

Answer (score 2):

As has been said, Drupal 7 is stable and currently on version 7.10.

I'd suggest [Drupal Commerce](http://drupal.org/project/commerce) for the shopping cart functionality, it's power comes in the fact it isn't build for a single use case and is more of a framework that site builders and other modules can build upon. It is also tightly integrated with views and rules, and is very much built the 'Drupal Way'. You'll find modules for [coupons](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_coupon) and [payment gateways](http://www.drupalcommerce.org/contrib/payment) along with many others to extend the (purposefully) limited Drupal Commerce functionality.

Add on to this the fact that one of Drupal's strong points is it's users, roles and permissions system, along with loads of content [access modules](http://drupal.org/project/modules?filters=tid:13434%20drupal_core:103%20bs_project_sandbox:0&solrsort=sis_project_release_usage%20desc) and a brilliant menu system.

Drupal isn't the right choice in all cases but it seems the perfect choice for you needs in this case.

Comment: Good thinking. I need bank transfer payment, which is here: http://drupal.org/project/commerce_bank_transfer - it says that it is still in development and not recommended for productive web pages.

Comment: Few notes - 1. just nowadays D7 will overcome D6 in numbers of downloads. This is a nice way to say that D7 is good and stable, while there are some cases where D6 is still a better answer. 2. If you do decide on D6, the "discounts_alt" module is a great solutions for the coupons requirement. 3. "Throw in" the Rules module, and you really get a strong and flexible solution for your needs. You are welcome to contact me for further help if needed. shushu.i@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

zen-cart does it

see [this](http://tutorials.zen-cart.com/index.php?article=336) for coupons, i mean it does it all, you can download [this](http://drupal.org/project/zencart) to integrate zen-cart with drupal, instead of doing it using drupal only

Comment: The Drupal integration is still in development. Doesn't seem like a stable alternative for a productive web page.

Comment: @Alp you can use zen cart on its own, without drupal, you can build a complete store using only zen-cart, nothing else, and then if you have lets say a blog on your site, you can install wordpress or drupal in another folder - zen cart to create the store and whatever cms for the blog

Comment: I need to have the same user base for both systems because the "shop" is just a way to let my users pay for the ability to view extended content.

Comment: @Alp well then, joomla is the most powerful php cms i can think of, and zen-cart is the most powerful eCommerce script... here's the zen-cart extension for joomla...what do you think about it? http://bit.ly/AgpvB1

Comment: you just have to find the right plugin because there are hundreds of plugins for every cms